# Trouble Replacing Text in HTML fragment using Mojo::DOM

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I need to scan through html fragments looking for certain strings in text (not within element attributes) and wrapping those matching strings with a `<span></span>`.  Here's a sample attempt with output:

```
use v5.10;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $body = qq|
<div>
<p>Boring Text:</p>
<p>
Highlight Cool whenever we see it.
but not <a href="/Cool.html">here</a>.
<code>
    sub Cool {
        print "Foo\n";
    }
</code>
And here is more Cool.
</p>
</div>
|;
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($body);

foreach my $e ($dom->find('*')->each) {
    my $text = $e->text;
    say "e text is:  $text ";
    if ($text =~ /Cool/) {
        (my $newtext = $text ) =~ s/Cool/<span class="fun">Cool<\/span>/g;
        $e->replace_content($newtext);
    }
}

say $dom->root;
```

the output:

```
e text is:   
e text is:  Boring Text: 
e text is:  Highlight Cool whenever we see it. but not. And here is more Cool. 
e text is:  here 
e text is:  sub Cool { print "Foo "; } 

<div>
<p>Boring Text:</p>
<p>Highlight <span class="fun">Cool</span> whenever we see it. but not. And here is more <span class="fun">Cool</span>.</p>
</div>
```

Close but what I really want to see is something like the following:

```
<div>
<p>Boring Text:</p>
<p>Highlight <span class="fun">Cool</span> whenever we see it. but not <a href="/Cool.html">here</a>. 
<code>
sub <span class="fun">Cool<span> { 
    print "Foo\n"; 
}
</code>  
And here is more <span class="fun">Cool</span>.</p>
</div>
```

Any help / pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Todd

Comment: Because of `Mojo::DOM`'s restriction to CSS selectors it's very difficult to do this. Are you restricted to using this module, or could you go to `XML::Twig` or another module that allows XPath access to the data?

Comment: No restrictions, I'll start looking into XML::Twig.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked into `XML::Twig` I'm not so sure it's the correct tool. It's surprising how awkward such a simple task can be.

This is a working program that uses [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder). Unfortunately it doesn't produce formatted output so I've added some whitespace myself.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(<<__HTML__);
<div>
<p>Boring Text:</p>
<p>
Highlight Cool whenever we see it.
but not <a href="/Cool.html">here</a>.
<code>
    sub Cool {
        print "Foo\n";
    }
</code>
And here is more Cool.
</p>
</div>
__HTML__

$html->objectify_text;

for my $text_node ($html->look_down(_tag => '~text')) {

  my $text = $text_node->attr('text');

  if (my @replacement = process_text($text)) {
    my $old_node = $text_node->replace_with(@replacement);
    $old_node->delete;
  }
}

$html->deobjectify_text;

print $html->guts->as_XML;

sub process_text {

  my @nodes = split /\bCool\b/, shift;
  return unless @nodes > 1;

  my $span = HTML::Element->new('span', class => 'fun');
  $span->push_content('Cool');

  for (my $i = 1; $i < @nodes; $i += 2) {
    splice @nodes, $i, 0, $span->clone;
  }

  $span->delete;

  @nodes;
}
```

**output**

```
<div>
<p>Boring Text:</p>
<p>
Highlight <span class="fun">Cool</span> whenever we see it.
but not <a href="/Cool.html">here</a>.
<code> sub <span class="fun">Cool</span> { print &quot;Foo &quot;; } </code>
And here is more <span class="fun">Cool</span>.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's more difficult as it seems at first sight. For example, this script doesn't handle correctly the newline of the `print` function either.

Comment: @Birei: "newline of the print function"?

Comment: Inside `<code>` tag it has a `print "Foo\n";` that is mangled in output.

Comment: @Birei: It uses entities to encode the double quotes. That is all. The equivalent text is the same.

Comment: having looked at both, I think I prefer this.  I will actually be replacing "Cool" with several regexes and this is more straight forward in HTML::TreeBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start using `XML::Twig`. One issue is the literal newline inside `<code>` tag. I guess that the parser cannot see the difference between it and a normal one. Perhaps it would help to encode it as `&#10` or use `CDATA` sections. Otherwise I don't know how to handle it:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $body = qq| 
<div>
<p>Boring Text:</p>
<p>
Highlight Cool whenever we see it.
but not <a href="/Cool.html">here</a>.
<code>
    sub Cool {
        print "Foo\n";
    }
</code>
And here is more Cool.
</p>
</div>
|;

XML::Twig::Elt::set_replaced_ents(q{});
my $elt = XML::Twig::Elt->new( 'span' => { class => 'fun' }, 'Cool' );

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'nice' )->parse( $body );
$twig->subs_text( 'Cool', $elt->sprint );
$twig->print;
```

Running it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

It yields:

```
<div>
<p>Boring Text:</p>
<p>
Highlight <span class="fun">Cool</span>
 whenever we see it.
but not <a href="/Cool.html">here</a>.
<code>
    sub <span class="fun">Cool</span>
 {
        print "Foo
";
    }
</code>
And here is more <span class="fun">Cool</span>
.
</p>
</div>
```